# Что такое @@YAHAAD@ (name mangling)?

Tags: c++, name-mangling

Есть `.lib` библиотека. Необходимо восстановить заголовочный файл для управления программой(все функции имеют одно название `H` и отличаются только аргументами, собственно они-то меня и интересуют). В поисках возможных вариантов проблемы наткнулся на программу `dumpbin /all`. Выполнил её и нашел фрагмент, из которого можно вытащить аргументы функций

```
 26 public symbols

    2 ?H@@YAHAAD@Z
```

Далее проанализировав уже найденные перегрузкой аргументы (например,

```
int H(bool))
```

Выяснил что символ `z` заменяет `;`, `H` заменяет `int`, `D` заменяет `char`, `N` заменяет `double`.

С остальными не могу сообразить сам. Поиски в интернете не помогли (возможно потому что не совсем понимаю, что это за язык). Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался и может объяснить, что это означает.

Comment: См. https://demangler.com/ и https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дам оказалось сильно проще , чем я думал.Перевод осуществляется с помощью команды undname в той же строке разработчика(Developer Command Prompt for VS). Более подробно здесь:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=vs-2019

Comment: Стоит добавить в ответ информацию кроме ссылки. Тем более в майкросвоте любят удалять старые страницы справки.